# asp.net Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.DataTable' Using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a question, why i get the error:

> **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type System.Data.DataTable**

```
Protected Sub gvInqProqurement_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Try
        If e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew") Then
            Dim txtItem As TextBox = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("txtItem")
            Dim txtItemMaterial As TextBox = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("txtItemMaterial")
            Dim txtItemDesc As TextBox = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("txtItemDesc")
            Dim txtItemSize As TextBox = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("txtItemSize")
            Dim txtItemBrand As TextBox = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("txtItemBrand")
            Dim txtItemQty As TextBox = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("txtItemQty")
            Dim ddlItemUnit As DropDownList = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("ItemUnit")
            Dim txtCerNeeds As TextBox = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCerNeeds")
            Dim txtRemarks As TextBox = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("txtRemarks")
            Dim hfItem As HiddenField = gvInqProqurement.FooterRow.FindControl("hfItem")

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtItem.Text) Then
                Throw New Exception("Invalid Data. Item Must Be Filled In.")
            End If

            Dim dtItem As New DataTable
            dtItem = ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem")

            For i As Integer = 0 To dtItem.Rows.Count - 1
                If hfItem.Value = dtItem.Rows(i).Item("FKItem").ToString Then
                    Throw New Exception("Item Already Selected.")
                End If
            Next


            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtItem.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()) Then
                dtItem.Rows.Add()
            Else
                gvInqProqurement.Rows(0).Cells(9).Visible = True
                gvInqProqurement.Rows(0).Cells(10).Visible = True
            End If
            dtItem.Rows(dtItem.Rows.Count - 1).Item("ItemCode") = txtItem.Text
            dtItem.Rows(dtItem.Rows.Count - 1).Item("ItemMaterial") = txtItemMaterial.Text
            dtItem.Rows(dtItem.Rows.Count - 1).Item("ItemDescription") = txtItemDesc.Text
            dtItem.Rows(dtItem.Rows.Count - 1).Item("ItemSize") = txtItemSize.Text
            dtItem.Rows(dtItem.Rows.Count - 1).Item("BrandName") = txtItemBrand.Text
            dtItem.Rows(dtItem.Rows.Count - 1).Item("Quantity_InqProcurement") = txtItemQty.Text
            dtItem.Rows(dtItem.Rows.Count - 1).Item("FKUnit") = ddlItemUnit.SelectedValue
            dtItem.Rows(dtItem.Rows.Count - 1).Item("FKCertificate") = txtItemQty.Text
            dtItem.Rows(dtItem.Rows.Count - 1).Item("Remarks") = txtItemQty.Text

            ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem") = dtItem

            gvInqProqurement.DataSource = dtItem
            gvInqProqurement.DataBind()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.cvErrorMessage.IsValid = False
        Me.cvErrorMessage.ErrorMessage = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

how do i fix this error?

Comment: Which `If ... Then` corresponds to the final `End If`?

Comment: Q: Exactly what line is the error occurring on?  Q: What is "ViewState()"?  Q: Where does the final "End If" in your code belong - is there some relevant code at the top we're missing?

Comment: Where do you get the error? It's certainly not in the code above. @paulsm4: [`Control.ViewState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: i think that i get the error at the line of :  ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem") = dtItem
            gvInqProqurement.DataSource = dtItem
            gvInqProqurement.DataBind() ..i'm beginner using VB, it's first time i'm using viewstate()

Comment: Shouldn't **ToString** have circular bracket in following line `dtItem.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString`. Doesn't it should look like `dtItem.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()`

Comment: @Suprabhat - VB doesn't require parentheses on method calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the value returned from the viewstate into DataTable by using the `Ctype`. You can even use `DirectCast`

```
Dim dtItem As New DataTable
if ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem") isnot nothing then
    dtItem = CType(ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem"),DataTable)
end if
```

You might have to think about the case when it is null...

Comment: i try your code, and now i'm getting the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' could you tell me why i get this error ?

Comment: most likely your viewstate does not contain "InqProcurement_New.dtItem". You can check if it is not null before the cast ...something like If ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem") IsNot Nothing Then
 dtItem = CType(ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem"),DataTable)
End If

Comment: @martinportgas: Does my code help? If yes, can you please mark the answer as accepted and upvote if possible.

Answer (score 0):

just change the following Code

```
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem").Tostring())=false then

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.Tostring(dtItem.Rows(0).Item(0))) Then
            dtItem.Rows.Add()
        Else
            gvInqProqurement.Rows(0).Cells(9).Visible = True
            gvInqProqurement.Rows(0).Cells(10).Visible = True
        End If
```

> in this case if u use .ToString() method then our program should throw null reference exception. and in Convert.ToString() our program doesn't throw any exception. bcoz by default it takes a blank value instead of null.

Comment: i have been trying, and i've just got the same error

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not the reason for the error you are having but you may have a syntax error in the first line.

this line:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtItem.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString) Then
```

should be as follows:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtItem.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()) Then
```

Comment: i have changed the codes, and i just get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of the `ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem")`  in the line             `dtItem = ViewState("InqProcurement_New.dtItem")`

It may return a string value.